# Swift vs C Bridge Enumeration Internals and Metadata

Tags: c, swift, objective-c

**Question:**

Why aren't the outputs the same for what are basically the same enumeration? Does Swift strip metadata from C (I assume it is stripped by the Compiler, then provided again by the Swift Interface File as though it is a normal Swift enum)?

**Details:**

I have two similar enumerations, one defined in C and one defined in Swift.

However I'm getting different print results, specifically the Swift Enum is able to print the key as a representational String (in this case `first`), but the C Enum is only able to print the Enumeration name (in this case `CNames`).

This is the output of the program,

```
Enumerations in Swift and C
Running on Swift 5
CNames is 1
first is 1
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I assume the Swift main file is using the Swift Generated Interface.

1. This is what my project looks like:

   [image: Project Hierarchy showing all four files in TestAppMain Group in TestApp Project]
2. Here's my native Swift enum, `SNames:

   ```
   //
   //  SNames.swift
   //  TestAppMain
   //

   import Foundation

   public enum SNames : UInt {
       case unknown = 0
       case first = 1
       case middle = 2
       case last = 3
   }
   ```
3. Here is my C enum, `CNames`:

   ```objectivec
   #ifndef Names_h
   #define Names_h

   // NSUInteger type definition
   #import <Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h>

   typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, CNames) {
       NameUnknown = 0,
       NameFirst   = 1,
       NameMiddle  = 2,
       NameLast    = 3,
   };

   #endif /* Names_h */
   ```
4. Here's the generated Swift 5 **Interface**:

   ```
   // NSUInteger type definition
   import Foundation.NSObjCRuntime

   public enum CNames : UInt {
       case unknown = 0
       case first = 1
       case middle = 2
       case last = 3
   }
   ```
5. Here is my bridging header:

   ```c
   #ifndef TestAppMain_Bridging_Header_h
   #define TestAppMain_Bridging_Header_h

   #import "CNames.h"

   #endif /* TestAppMain_Bridging_Header_h */
   ```
6. Finally my `main.swift` is:

   ```
   print("Enumerations in Swift and C")
   #if swift(>=5)
       print("Running on Swift 5")
   #endif

   let cFirst = CNames.first
   let sFirst = SNames.first

   // Swift Enum is able to output the specific
   // case (i.e first) whereas the C Enum
   // doesn't seem to have that info
   // CNames is 1
   print("\(cFirst) is \(cFirst.rawValue)")
   // first is 1
   print("\(sFirst) is \(sFirst.rawValue)")
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a limitation of C. C enums are nothing more than a visually grouped set of integer constants.

You'll notice that you get the same limitations when applying `@objc` to Swift enums:

```swift
enum NativeEnum: Int32 { case i = 123 }
print(NativeEnum.i) // => "i"

@objc enum ExportedEnum: Int32 { case i = 123 }
print(ExportedEnum.i) // => "ExportedEnum"
```

Comment: I kind of figured that was what it was (since the compiler strips metadata anyways for C enums). I was hoping somehow the Swift Interface would 'restore' that info but I guess not :).  I was just trying to log the actual names of `XCUIElement.ElementType` which seems to proxy the C enum `XCUIElementType` vs their integer values. So in the end not a big deal :).

Comment: "I was hoping somehow the Swift Interface would 'restore' that info" Ugh, me too, it really would make things so much nicer. My app interops with a fair number of C enums, so I end up having switch-statements full of string literals to "get back" that name information.